# Vanishing terms in Sumation of an orthoganl integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, orthogonality

I reached the following expression after carrying out the integral

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^L \cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{nL((-1)^{n+k}-1)}{\pi(k^2-n^2)}$$

Can anything be said about the summation on the RHS, like which terms woud vanish?

Comment: when do you think $(-1)^{n+k} - 1$ vanishes? Also your formula cannot be correct for $k^2=n^2$ as the denominator explodes

Comment: You should handle the integral for $n=k$ separately. The sum on RHS is not meaningful.